# exporting archive file from android studio

Tags: export, android-studio

It would appear as if android studio has no "export project" command... can this possibly be true? I'm kind of freaking out because my class requires an archive file, and it would almsot appear as if android studio has a different build structure then eclipse. help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is using new build structure (with gradle). It is in preview stage. I believe when Studio will come up from it to stable version, Eclipse will be updated to to new structure too. Until then if you want to use your projects in old project format with, you have to create new projects with old tools (aka Eclipse, Intellij, console tools etc) and then use with Android Studio.